# Pinescript: Old scripts with self-referencing variables

Tags: variables, version, pine-script, self-reference

I have to old scripts (V2) I want to modify only for myself and dont reach out anyone to help me out with my bad coding skills ;)

The code looks that way:

weight = s(abs(change(close)))

**c = weight * close + (1-weight) * nz(c[1],close)**

(error comes with c, because, I think, it's a self-referencing variable)

Maybe somone can help me out how to declare c for pinescript4 in that case.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/appendix/Pine_version_3_migration_guide.html#self-referenced-variables-are-removed) can help:

```
//@version=2
//...
s = nz(s[1]) + close
Compiling this piece of code with Pine version 3 will give you an Undeclared identifier 's' error. It should be rewritten as:
```

```
//@version=3
//...
s = 0.0
s := nz(s[1]) + close // ok
```

Your code:

```
//@version=3
study("My script")
weight = abs(change(close))
c = 0.
c := weight * close + (1-weight) * nz(c[1],close)
plot(c)
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately not. Same error, only with that line: 

**c = weight * close + (1-weight) * nz(c[1],close)**

Comment: Answer is updated